# Java: getClass() breaks out of method?

Tags: java, debugging

I have a line of code followed by a for loop that makes a call to getClass().

```
Class<?> type = track.getClass();
for (Field field : getAllFields(type)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I set breakpoints on the first line and another on the header of the for loop. During a debug, the first line is hit, but after hitting continue (in the NetBeans debugger), the for loop never gets hit. I also placed breakpoints further down in the method, but they were not hit either. I'm unsure what's happening in the first line that breaks out of the method. If anyone could offer some advice, I'd be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that `track` is `null`, and the exception is bubbling out?

Comment: For us to help you, it would help if you'd provide a [mcve] which didn't rely on a debugger. (Add diagnostic tracing and include the output in the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the debugger step in to inspect what track is. Is it null? You should see an exception if it is occurring.

You could also wrap your .getClass() in a try catch and print out any exceptions if you are not that experienced with the debugger yet.

Answer (score 0):

Track was indeed null... Can't believe I missed that.
Thanks for the help.